# Exporting ECW using ArcPy gives python.exe has stopped working

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, export, ecw

I work with ArcView 10.3. Every time i export maps with ecw raster format , python (version 2.7.8) get crashed and i see:

[image]

I use this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\yaron\shonot\software\gis\maps\gis"
counter = 0
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print (mxd) # print list of mxd's in the folder
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\yaron\shonot\software\gis\maps\gis\\" + mxd)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, r"C:\yaron\shonot\software\gis\maps\gis\output\\"+os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace ('.mxd','') +".jpg",resolution=196)
    print ('ExportToJPEG')
    mapdoc.save()
    counter = counter + 1
del mxd 
print (counter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ecw file.

In ArcMap 10.3 python gets stuck with the ecw file.

I converted the ecw to tif. file